# Formatting and aligning string text in android button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to shift and format the string text inside my android button to the center or center right. I am surprised I have been unable to find a solution.

Anyways this is how my xml screen looks:

[image: App Button]

Many of the solutions require me to use layout gravity. However I used layout gravity to format my icon so I am unsure how to fix this in this case.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/block_apps"
        android:textSize="22sp"

        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/security_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blacklist_whitelist_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that `layout_gravity` is not the same as `gravity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/block_apps"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/security_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blacklist_whitelist_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="right">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action"
            android:text="@string/block_apps"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/security_settings_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blacklist_whitelist_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```